# Is it possible to check if two numbers are equal only with arithmetic operators?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to find a function f(x,y) that returns 1 if the numbers are equal or 0 otherwise.

But I cannot wrap my head around it since I can't use functions like floor/ceil/absolute val.

Comment: Are all functions you are allowed to use continuous? Are you allowed to use limits?

Comment: just arithmetic operators

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This suggestion may raise a heated discussion, but
$$f(x,y)=0^{(x-y)^2}$$
works. Note that $0^0=1$ whereas $0^a=0$ for any $a>0$.

Comment: This is a very interesting and creative idea but I note that there is not a consensus on the value of $0^{0}$. Possibilities include $0$, $1$ and undefined. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_power_of_zero

Comment: @SimonTerrington The heated discussion has begun!

Comment: :) and by the way I don't have a better idea and I really like your answer.